# How to connect android kotlin to sails js using socket.io

Tags: android, kotlin, socket.io, sails.js

I don't know what I am doing wrong,

This is my code in kotlin using socket io client:

```kotlin
    val mSocket: Socket = IO.socket("http://10.24.17.45:1337/socket.io/?__sails_io_sdk_version=1.2.1&__sails_io_sdk_platform=browser&__sails_io_sdk_language=javascript&EIO=3&transport=websocket");

        val jsonArray = JSONArray()
        val header  = JSONObject()
        val headers = JSONObject()
        val data    = JSONObject()


        headers.put("usertoken","\$2a\$10GbowyVBWXielcthStNASzOKa40FP1wtexhv3HAZ.XHE5J.K.IrIcK")
        headers.put("apptoken","apptoken")
        headers.put("userid","3")

        header.put("method","get")
        header.put("headers",headers)
        header.put("data",data)
        header.put("url","wss://10.24.17.45:1337/notifications")


        //jsonArray.put("get")
        jsonArray.put(header)


        mSocket!!.emit("get", header)
        mSocket!!.connect()
```

And this is my code in SailsJS:

```js
    notificationsJoin: function(req, res) {
    try{
            if (!req.isSocket) {
                res.status(500)
                return res.send(ack.createResponse(500,"","No es una solicitud de tipo WS."));
            }
            res.ok("connection succes")
        } catch(err){
            res.status(500)
            return res.send(ack.createResponse(500,"",err.message));
        }
    }
```

And finally, this is my route

`'get /notifications': 'NotificationController.notificationsJoin',`

Answer (score 0):

Check this Documentation: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/sails-sockets

the blast and broadcast would send messages to client that are joined.

You might want to create an endpoint to join your clients to sails js socket.

```
subscribeToNotifications: function(req, res) {
  if (!req.isSocket) {
    return res.badRequest();`enter code here`
  }

  var roomName = req.param('notifications');
  sails.sockets.join(req, roomName, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.serverError(err);
    }

    return res.json({
      message: 'Subscribed to a room called '+roomName+'!'
    });
  });
}
```

Then for broadcast
`sails.sockets.broadcast('notifications', { greeting: 'Hola!' });`

Then on your client

```
io.socket.on('message', function (data){
  console.log(data.greeting);
});
```